# Magento: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'billing_name' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Trying to filter an admin grid to view sales history on specific products, but getting the following error when trying to filter by Billing name:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'billing_name' in 'where clause'`

Here is what I'm using:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    $ordersId = $this->getOrderIds($productId);

    $collection = mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id', array('in' => $ordersId))
                ->join('sales/order_address', '`sales/order_address`.entity_id=billing_address_id', array('billing_name' => "concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)"));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

And then to add grid column for Billing Name:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('AdvancedStock')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
        'sortable' => true
    ));

return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

The column returns all billing names from orders containing the product correctly, I just can't filter the column by name.  Any ideas?

Comment: You've added the billing name to the model but not the database? Does it exist when you view the `sales_flat_order` (or is it the `sales_flat_order_address`) table?

Comment: @CD001 I believe it's in `sales_flat_order_address` although I don't have access to phpMyAdmin to check tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magento sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_address tables will not have the column billing_name.
    You can use sales_flat_order_grid table instead of sales_flat_order_address for getting the billing_name like this,

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id', array('in' => $ordersId))
                    ->join('sales/order_grid', '`sales/order_grid`.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('billing_name' => 'billing_name'));
```

Otherwise, you can Leftjoin the sales_flat_order_grid table with the current collection.

Comment: Great :). Thank you